# SEVERE: Context [/yacceleratorstorefront] startup failed due to previous errors

Tags: macos, e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

I am installing hybris on MAC (i5 - 500gb - 4gb)

I am getting this type of errors and I am not able to access localhost:9001

Friends please help me out.

Below is the log file details

```
Nov 14, 2014 11:44:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart

Nov 14, 2014 11:44:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/yacceleratorstorefront] startup failed due to previous errors

Nov 14, 2014 11:44:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9001"]

Nov 14, 2014 11:44:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9002"]

Nov 14, 2014 11:44:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Nov 14, 2014 11:44:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 257151 ms
```

Comment: Can you provide full stacktrace?

Comment: We need the full error !

Answer (score 1):

There is a error in starting the web application of yacceleratorstorefront. So either you can Comment out yaccelerator extensions from your localextensions.xml or solve the error thrown in yacceleratorstorefront.